# How to get ttf font data from system fonts in java

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, truetype

I have some ttf fonts installed on system.

I get that list using

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames()
```

This is not only ttf fonts but all fonts I guess.
Eventually if I use:

```
Font.decode(fontName)
```

I can get awt.Font instance.

As far as I know Font is not connected to actual PhysicalFont, so
how can I retrieve either ttf font file, or byte data from that ttf file for a font from that list or from awt.Font ? I am trying to retrieve a physical font data or anything similar. That data should be somewhere right?

The reason I need it is to eventually use with libGDX 
FreeTypeFontGenerator in order to generate BitmapFont

This has to work on windows, osx and linux.

Comment: Basically what I can do is get for each system it's font directory path, then list of all ttf files in it, then iterate on it, and for each ttf file create an wtf font to get it's pretty name, and then make a map from that. but this usually take around 15 seconds time. Which is not an option.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible. The best you can do is [using reflection](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/hiero/unicodefont/UnicodeFont.java#L600), but it will only work with an Oracle JRE and accesses a private API so may break with any new Oracle release.

You could probably write a [native lib](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/jnigen) to enumerate the fonts and their files.

Comment: Thanks for answering Nate! I guess yes that's something troubled. My current solution is to "pre-cache" a map of font name -> file name at the first run, and then just update that data. It is slow, and maybe later I can get back to this, and make a native lib to do that. But, I mean. weird that it is like that.

Answer (score 3):

As @NateS pointed out, it appears what I want to achieve is not exactly possible.

So I will just share the solution I used in my case for now:

Which is this class:
[FontManager.java](https://github.com/UnderwaterApps/overlap2d/blob/master/overlap2d/src/com/uwsoft/editor/proxy/FontManager.java)

This allows to pre-cache existing ttf files in known system locations based on your system, and then make a Map for fontName->fontFile type of connection. this then goes to preferences, and is loaded on next run.

Known issues are

1. awt.Font has a known bug that is not able to read some ttf font family names on osx systems (mainly some arabic and chinese fonts)
2. Did not test on Linux, will probably fail.
3. First run might be slow if you have many fonts.

It would be ideal to write a native lib, but time is of an essence...